# Telerik MVC Grid: Getting Parent Row Client-Side

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I am trying to get the value of a column in the parent row of a child row's onEdit event for a Telerik MVC Grid.  How would I achieve that?

e.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.innerHTML gives me table row of the parent row.  I now need to parse this to get the column data I want.  Someone know of a more elegant solution?

Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `$(e.target).parent('tr').find('td:nth-child(2)').text()`  where 2 is the column you want the contents of.

Comment: can you elaborate on what's not working?  perhaps add some html to the question, or create a jsfiddle?

Comment: This was answered by someone on telerik.com: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/grid/getting-parent-row-client-side.aspx.  But now I need to get the granparent of this child row.

Comment: @SteveB, if you've answered your question, please create an answer and mark it as the correct answer.  other people are much more likely to find your solution that way.

Comment: It hasn't been answered.  I need the grandparent row too.

Comment: @SteveB, you're going to have to add more detail to your question to get an answer.  without seeing the html i can't help you.